# With the product topology $(X^\omega)^\omega$ and $X^\omega$ are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

From some lecture notes:

[image: Lecture notes]

Here $a_n$ are sequences. The standard bijection in question is $\langle n, m \rangle = 2^n(2m + 1) - 1$. The topology on $Y^\omega$ is the product topology, both for $Y = X$ and $Y = X^\omega$.

I don't see why $h^{-1}$ is continuous, as any small change in $a \in X^\omega$ according to the metric (which induces the product topology):
$$ d(a, b) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } a = b \\\\
2^{-n} & \text{ if } a \upharpoonright n = b \upharpoonright n \land a(n) \neq b(n)
\end{cases}$$
impacts the sequence $(h^{-1}(a))(0)$ already. So that no matter the distance $d_{X^\omega}(a, b)$, we have $d_{(X^\omega)^\omega}((h^{-1}(a)), (h^{-1}(b))) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f: Y \to {{}^\omega}X$ is continuous (where the power has the product topology) iff $\forall n \in \omega: \pi_n \circ h: Y \to X$ is continuous where $\pi_n: {{}^\omega}X \to X;\, \pi_n(a)  =a(n)$ for all $n$ (the projection maps, which are always continuous on products). This is a standard fact about product topologies.

So with $\mathbb{h}_X$ we have that for $k \in \omega$ that $\pi_k \circ \mathbb{h}_X = \pi_n \circ \pi_m$ where $n,m$ are the unique members of $\omega$ such that $\langle n,m \rangle = k$, and this is a composition of two continous projections, hence continuous. So $\mathbb{h}_X$ is continuous.

For the inverse map (call it $\mathbb{k}$, say) we use a similar argument,
but then we have a "power of powers" so we need that $\pi_n \circ \pi_m \circ \mathbb{k}$ is continous for all $n,m$ but this just equals $\pi_{\langle n,m\rangle}$ (or the other order, it's late) and so just a (continous) projection again.

So both $\mathbb{h}_X$ and its inverse are continuous.

Comment: Yes, I get it (I think). But why do you prove the case $X^\omega \times X^\omega$? We need $(X^\omega)^\omega$, although I can see it is proved similarly.

Comment: @Jori Fixed it somewhat. The basic idea of moving coordinates around stays the same. And indeed $X^\omega$ is homeomorphic to its square as well.

Answer (score 2):

It’s easier to work directly with the product topology.

${^\omega}({^\omega}X)$ has a base consisting of sets $B$ of the following form. Let $F\subseteq\omega$ be finite, and for each $n\in F$ let $F_n$ be a finite subset of $\omega$. For each $n\in F$ and $k\in F_n$ let $U(n,k)$ be an open set in $X$. Let

$$B_n=\left\{a\in{^\omega}X:a(k)\in U(n,k)\text{ for each }k\in F_n\right\}\,,$$

a basic open set in ${^\omega}X$, and let

$$B=\left\{\langle a_n:n\in\omega\rangle\in{^\omega}({^\omega}X):a_n\in B_n\text{ for each }n\in F\right\}\,.$$

Let $a\in{^\omega}X$. Then $a\in h[B]$ iff there is $\langle a_n:n\in\omega\rangle\in{^\omega}({^\omega}X)$ such that $a=h(\langle a_n:n\in\omega\rangle)$ and $a_n(k)\in U(n,k)$ for each $n\in F$ and $k\in F_n$. But if $a=h(\langle a_n:n\in\omega\rangle)$, then $a(\langle n,k\rangle)=a_n(k)$ for each $n\in F$ and $k\in F_n$, so $a\in h[B]$ iff $a(\langle n,k\rangle)\in U(n,k)$ for each $n\in F$ and $k\in F_n$. That is,

$$h[B]=\left\{a\in{^\omega}X:a(\langle n,k\rangle)\in U(n,k)\text{ for each }n\in F\text{ and }k\in F_n\right\}\,,$$

which is open in ${^\omega}X$. Thus, $h$ is a continuous, open bijection and is therefore a homeomorphism.

Comment: Ah, my error was that I interpreted $(X^\omega)^\omega$ as the product topology of the discrete topology over $X^\omega$. So let me see: you prove that $h$ maps basic open sets to basic open sets (and so open sets to open sets), bijectively. Why is $h$ continuous? Does that follow from your explanation?

Comment: @Jori: Pretty much, yes: you just have to realize that the correspondence between basic open sets in one space and those in the other really is a bijection. What it all comes down to in the end is that ${^\omega}({^\omega}X)$ is homeomorphic (in a fairly obvious way) to ${^{(\omega\times\omega)}}X$, which is homeomorphic to ${^\omega}X$ because there is a bijection between $\omega\times\omega$ and $\omega$: each of these spaces is just the product of countably infinitely many copies of $X$.

Comment: I can see that. The "fairly obvious way" is what you've sketched in your proof, correct?

Comment: @Jori: Yes, you end up treating $\langle a_n:n\in\omega\rangle\in{^\omega}({^\omega}X)$ as a function from $\omega\times\omega$ to $X$ that takes $\langle n,k\rangle$ to $a_n(k)$.